# Exception access violation (msvcrt.dll)

Tags: vb.net, access-violation

I received silent crashes, and in order to find their reasons, I collected a crash dump. When I try to debug it, I get the error

> Exception thrown at 0x748E89EA (msvcrt.dll) in app.exe.10228.dmp:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0457351A.

I can’t find out exactly where this error occurs, because it occurs spontaneously during working. 
After all, in vb.net there is no direct memory access, where could this error be? Is it possible that it is from the dll files that the program uses?

Call stack of thread in which appeared exception:

```
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+c 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+133 
KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+18 
kernel32!WerpReportFaultInternal+3b7  kernel32!WerpReportFault+9d 
kernel32!BasepReportFault+19  KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+2a2 
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+3a4e6  ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b
```

Comment: Have you tried running in the debugger with the "Enable native code debugging" option set?  Right-click on the project and go to the "Debug" ply to find this option.

Comment: @Craig Of course, I've used all modes, include "native code".

Comment: I assume, then, that it hasn't happened while you're debugging?  Or, if it has, it's not giving you a useful call stack?  If you haven't already done so, you may want to make sure you have .pdb files for any of your own dll files used by the program.

Comment: There is no call stack and visible code in default visual studio debugger, it's just "silent crash", so I collected dump. But I got call stack from dump using DebugDiag, I've added it to the question.

Comment: You'd normally see the code that cause the crash before the UnhandledExceptionFilter() call.  But there's nothing, goes straight from RtlUserThreadStart to kaboom.  So you know nothing more than this is a very nasty crash that might be caused by stack corruption.  You might see more if you configure DebugDiag to trap on the "first chance exception", YMMV.  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Using-DebugDiag-to-capture-memory-dumps-on-First-Chance/ba-p/377131

Comment: Thanks, I will try to catch the "first chance exception" in the next crash. I can't cause a crash on my own, this happens only during real work so I will wait.